# gdb: how to disable a specific pretty-printer

Tags: gdb

How to disable a specific pretty-printer in gdb?
For example, disable C++11 std::unique_ptr printer.

gdb help or documentation doesn't give a real-world or working example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
(gdb) info pretty-printer
global pretty-printers:    
  libstdc++-v6
    ...        
    std::unique_ptr
    ...
(gdb) disable pretty-printer libstdc++-v6 std::unique_ptr
```

Source: https://www-zeuthen.desy.de/unix/unixguide/infohtml/gdb/Pretty_002dPrinter-Commands.html