# Registering a gdb pretty-printer for a specialization of std::unordered_map

Tags: c++, gdb, pretty-print

I'm trying to register a pretty-printer for a specific specialization of `std::unordered_map`, but for some reason it always uses the standard pretty-printer for `std::unordered_map` in gdb instead of my specialized version.

---

Consider the following class

```cpp
namespace ns {

class MyClass {
public:
    std::string name;
    int value = 0;
};

}  // namespace ns
```

I have a gdb pretty-printer defined for it as

```py
# myprinters.py -> sourced in gdb
class MyClassPrinter:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.name = val["name"]
        self.val = val["value"]

    def to_string(self):
        return f"MyClass(name={self.name}, value={self.val})"


import gdb.printing
pp = gdb.printing.RegexpCollectionPrettyPrinter('myprinters')
pp.add_printer('MyClass', 'MyClass', MyClassPrinter)

gdb.printing.register_pretty_printer(gdb.current_objfile(), pp, replace=True)
```

Now consider the main function below

```cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::tuple<int, MyClass> mytuple{10, {"name10", 10}};
    std::unordered_map<int, MyClass> mymap;
    mymap.insert({10, {"name10", 10}});
    mymap.insert({15, {"name15", 15}});
    mymap.insert({25, {"name25", 25}});

    auto myobj = MyClass{"name5", 5};

    std::unordered_map<int, MyClass *> mymap2;
    mymap2.insert({10, new MyClass{"name10", 10}});  // don't worry about the new
    mymap2.insert({15, new MyClass{"name15", 15}});
    mymap2.insert({25, new MyClass{"name25", 25}});

    std::cout << "The end" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If a add a breakpoint in the `cout` line and print `myobj`I get `$7 = MyClass(name="name5", value=5)` as expected. Printing `mytuple` and `mymap` also works, since gdb has pretty-printers for the containers in STL. We get something like

```
$8 = std::tuple containing = {
  [1] = 10,
  [2] = MyClass(name="name10", value=10)
}
$9 = std::unordered_map with 3 elements = {
  [25] = MyClass(name="name25", value=25),
  [15] = MyClass(name="name15", value=15),
  [10] = MyClass(name="name10", value=10)
}
```

However, what I actually have are containers with `MyClass*` and not `MyClass`, such as the `mymap2` variable. Printing that results in

```
$10 = std::unordered_map with 3 elements = {
  [25] = 0x555555576760,
  [15] = 0x555555576710,
  [10] = 0x555555576650
}
```

which is not very useful.

For my particular needs, I only need the "name" field of each `MyClass` object pointed in `mymap2`. Then I created a pretty-printer for `std::unordered_map<int, MyClass *>`, but I'm not able to register it correctly (maybe the version for just `std::unordered_map` is taking precedence, but I could not correctly disable to test this hypothesis. I get an error when I try to disable the pretty-printer as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48519897/gdb-how-to-disable-a-specific-pretty-printer)).

I tried with

```py
class MyUnorderedMapOfMyClassPrinter:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def to_string(self):
        return "MyUnorderedMapOfMyClassPrinter"
```

and then added the line below to the python script defining my pretty-printers

```py
pp.add_printer('MyUnorderedMapOfMyClassPrinter', 'std::unordered_map<int, ns::MyClass\*>', MyUnorderedMapOfMyClassPrinter)
```

to include the new pretty-printer.

But printing the unordered_map does not use my pretty-printer. It still uses the regular `std::unordered_map` pretty-printer from gdb.

If I do create a new type like

```cpp
class MyUnorderedMap : public std::unordered_map<int, MyClass *> {};
```

and register a pretty-printer for `MyUnorderedMap` then it works. But I don't want to create another type just to be able to register a pretty-printer.

**How can I register a pretty-printer for a specific specialization of `std::unordered_map`?**

---

**Edit:**
I could not disable only the `std::unordered_map` pretty-printer, but
I disabled all pretty-printers with `disable pretty-printer` in gdb, and then enabled only my pretty-printers with `enable pretty-printer global myprinters`. This allowed me try the regexp to register my pretty-printer and to make it work for a std::unordered_map specialization with with `pp.add_printer('MyUnorderedMapOfMyClassPrinter', 'std::unordered_map<.*, ns::MyClass\*>', MyUnorderedMapOfMyClassPrinter)` (note the "*" at the end, since I only want it to work for `MyClass` pointers).

Interesting, `pp.add_printer('MyUnorderedMapOfMyClassPrinter', 'std::unordered_map<int, ns::MyClass\*>', MyUnorderedMapOfMyClassPrinter)`
**did not work**. I had to use `.*` instead of `int`to make it work for some reason.

However, when all pretty-printers are enabled the standard `std::unordered_map` pretty printer still takes precedence over my specialization. **How can I make my pretty-printer takes precedence?**

---

For making things easily reproducible, here is the full `main.cpp` file

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <unordered_map>

namespace ns {

class MyClass {
public:
    std::string name;
    int value = 0;
};

}  // namespace ns

using namespace ns;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::tuple<int, MyClass> mytuple{10, {"name10", 10}};
    std::unordered_map<int, MyClass> mymap;
    mymap.insert({10, {"name10", 10}});
    mymap.insert({15, {"name15", 15}});
    mymap.insert({25, {"name25", 25}});

    auto myobj = MyClass{"name5", 5};

    std::unordered_map<int, MyClass *> mymap2;
    mymap2.insert({10, new MyClass{"name10", 10}});
    mymap2.insert({15, new MyClass{"name15", 15}});
    mymap2.insert({25, new MyClass{"name25", 25}});

    std::cout << "The end" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

and the full `myprinters.py` file defining the pretty-printers

```py
class MyClassPrinter:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.name = str(val["name"])
        self.val = val["value"]

    def to_string(self):
        return f"MyClass(name={self.name}, value={self.val})"


class MyClassPointerPrinter:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.ptr = val
        self.name = str(val.dereference()["name"])
        self.val = val.dereference()["value"]

    def to_string(self):
        return f"Pointer to MyClass(name={self.name}, value={self.val})"



class MyUnorderedMapOfMyClassPrinter:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def to_string(self):
        return "MyUnorderedMapOfMyClassPrinter"


import gdb.printing
pp = gdb.printing.RegexpCollectionPrettyPrinter('myprinters')
pp.add_printer('MyClass', '^ns::MyClass$', MyClassPrinter)
# pp.add_printer('MyClass', 'MyClass\*', MyClassPointerPrinter)
# pp.add_printer('MyClass', 'MyClass.?\*', MyClassPointerPrinter)
# pp.add_printer('MyClass', 'MyClass \*', MyClassPointerPrinter)
pp.add_printer('MyUnorderedMapOfMyClassPrinter', 'std::unordered_map<.*, ns::MyClass\*>', MyUnorderedMapOfMyClassPrinter)


gdb.printing.register_pretty_printer(gdb.current_objfile(), pp, replace=True)



def my_pp_func(val):
    if str(val.type) == "ns::MyClass *":
        return MyClassPointerPrinter(val)

gdb.pretty_printers.append(my_pp_func)
```

Comment: I'm still wondering why you don't create a pretty-printer for `MyClass*`.

Comment: That would indeed work in this particular case, but I could not get it to work. I tryied `pp.add_printer('MyClass', 'MyClass\*', MyClassPointerPrinter)`, then `pp.add_printer('MyClass', 'MyClass.?\*', MyClassPointerPrinter)`, then `pp.add_printer('MyClass', 'MyClass \*', MyClassPointerPrinter)`, but nothing seem to work when registering  pretty printer for a pointer. Do you have a suggestion about what I could try as the regexp?

Comment: Yes, instead of a `RegexpCollectionPrettyPrinter`, use a lookup function.

Comment: I also tried that. I defined the function 
`def my_pp_func(val):
    if str(val.type) == "ns::MyClass *":
        return MyClassPointerPrinter(val)`
and registered with `gdb.pretty_printers.append(my_pp_func)`.

In gdb python-interactive,I confirmed that calling `my_pp_func` with an object of type `MyClass *` correctly returns the pretty-printer object, thus `my_pp_func` seems correct. But still it has no effect when registering the pretty-printer with `gdb.pretty_printers.append(my_pp_func)`.

Comment: That is why I was led to beleive that I could not register pretty-printers for pointers and I changed my approach to register a pretty-printer for a specialization of the `unordered_map`.

Comment: That is why I was led to beleive that I could not register pretty-printers for pointers and I changed my approach to register a pretty-printer for a specialization of the `unordered_map`.

Comment: Do you still have the full code for this so I can try to reproduce it (c++ and pretty-printer)?

Comment: I have add both the main.cpp and the myprinters.py file to the question.

Comment: If I remove the `pp.add_printer('MyUnorderedMapOfMyClassPrinter', ...)` call, it works for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231485/discussion-between-darcamo-and-ssbssa).

Answer (score 2):

For me, the problem is that `gdb.current_objfile()` always returns `None`. Thus your pretty printer is registered as a global one, whereas all the standard ones are object level. Object level pretty-printers take precedence.

I have no idea why, but I was unable to make this function work.

It is possible to use this workaround:

```
gdb.printing.register_pretty_printer(gdb.objfiles()[0], pp, replace=True)
```

Comment: I noticed that `gdb.current_objfile()` returned None, which seems to indicate that the pretty-printer is registered as a global one, instead of being in a specific objfile. But this does not seem to be related to the issue. I was able to make it work with a lookup funtion after removing `pp.add_printer('MyUnorderedMapOfMyClassPrinter', ...)`.

Comment: Object pretty-printers take precedence over global ones.

Answer (score 2):

After more investigation and comments in the question from "n. 'pronouns' m.", I was able to solve the problem, although the question is still technically not solved.

In summary, with

```py
class MyUnorderedMapOfMyClassPrinter:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def to_string(self):
        return "MyUnorderedMapOfMyClassPrinter"


import gdb.printing
pp = gdb.printing.RegexpCollectionPrettyPrinter('myprinters')
pp.add_printer('MyClass', '^ns::MyClass$', MyClassPrinter)
pp.add_printer('MyUnorderedMapOfMyClassPrinter', 'std::unordered_map<.*, ns::MyClass\*>', MyUnorderedMapOfMyClassPrinter)
```

a pretty printer is registered for my specialization of `unordered_map`. However, **the version for the general `unordered_map` is still used** and if I print the `mymap2`variable the string `"MyUnorderedMapOfMyClassPrinter"` is **not shown** as expected. If we disable all pretty printers and enable only our pretty-printers, then "MyUnorderedMapOfMyClassPrinter" is shown, thus confirming that it was correctly registered. That is why the question is technically not solved, since disabling all other pretty-printers is not a good solution.

But registering a pretty-printer for `MyClass*` does work, as suggested in the comments, as long as we use a lookup function instead of relying on the `RegexpCollectionPrettyPrinter`. This solves the original problem, since the gdb regular pretty-printer for `unordered_map` will now be enough.

More specifically, we can create a pretty-printer as

```py
class MyClassPointerPrinter:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.ptr = val
        self.name = str(val.dereference()["name"])
        self.val = val.dereference()["value"]

    def to_string(self):
        return f"Pointer to MyClass(name={self.name}, value={self.val})"
```

and register it with

```py
def my_pp_func(val):
    if str(val.type) == "ns::MyClass *":
        return MyClassPointerPrinter(val)


gdb.pretty_printers.append(my_pp_func)
```

---

We can even extend this further and create a pretty-printer for **any pointer**. For instance, we can define a pretty printer as

```py
class MyPointerPrettyPrinter:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.ptr = val

    def to_string(self):
        default_visualizer = gdb.default_visualizer(self.ptr.dereference())
        return f"({self.ptr.type}) {self.ptr.format_string(raw=True)} -> {default_visualizer.to_string()}"
```

and register it with

```py
def my_pointer_func(val):
    # This matches any pointer
    if val.type.code == gdb.TYPE_CODE_PTR:
        # Only if the pointed object has a registered pretty-printer we will use
        # our pointer pretty-printer
        if gdb.default_visualizer(val.dereference()) is not None:
            return MyPointerPrettyPrinter(val)


gdb.pretty_printers.append(my_pointer_func)
```

This will match any pointer and print something like "(ClassName *) 0x<pointer_address> -> OBJ_REP", where "OBJ_REP" is the pretty-printing of the pointed object. If there is no visualizer registered for `ClassName`, then only "(ClassName *) 0x<pointer_address>" is shown.