# How to overload gdb pretty-printer for template class of specific type

Tags: gdb, pretty-print

I want my gdb pretty-printer to print a variable of type: `std::shared_ptr<myClass>`

How should I register my printer such that it overrides the default shared_ptr printer?

Comment: I don't think you can override a printer, but you can disable the `std::shared_ptr` printer completely. Is there a reason you don't want to use the normal pretty-printer?

Comment: Because myClass is a complex entity and I want selective things to be printed. Its not just about shared_ptr, it can be any other template class, like std::vector<myClass>. I want to use default printer for everything else, but when the template uses myClass then it should prefer the specialized printer

Comment: So, you already have a pretty-printer for myClass?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67200091/registering-a-gdb-pretty-printer-for-a-specialization-of-stdunordered-map).